# Tengo un problema con la función de XMLHttpRequest ya que no guarda el dato que quiero recuperar en mi archivo php

Tags: javascript, php

La cosa es la siguiente en mi proyecto quiero guardar el Id de una tabla de mi base de datos, para hacerlo, hice lo siguiente.

Realice mi conexión a mi base de datos agregue una variable para recuperar el Id de cada fila con sus datos correspondientes y asi poder cargar cada Id y sus datos en mi pagina HTML.

**Inserto el Codigo**
(Cabe aclarar que no tiene ningun problema este bloque solo lo pongo como referencia)

```
<?php

  session_start();
  // Conexión a la base de datos
  $conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'cine');

  // Verificar si la conexión es exitosa
  if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Error en la conexión a la base de datos: " . $conn->connect_error);
  }

  // Verificar si se envió una solicitud de eliminación
  if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST' && isset($_POST['ticket_id'])) {
    $ticketId = $_POST['ticket_id'];

    // Obtener el nombre de la película
    $query = "SELECT Pelicula FROM tickets WHERE id = $ticketId";
    $result = $conn->query($query);
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
    $peliculaNombre = $row['Pelicula'];

    // Mostrar una alerta de confirmación en el navegador
    echo '<script>';
    echo 'if (confirm("¿Estás seguro de que deseas eliminar el registro de ' . $peliculaNombre . '?")) {';
    echo '  window.location.href = "eliminar.php?ticket_id=' . $ticketId . '";';
    echo '}';
    echo '</script>';
  }

  // Obtener los datos desde la base de datos
  $ticketQuery = "SELECT id, Imagen, Pelicula, Nombre, NomT, Pais, Cine, Texto, Personas, Horario FROM tickets";
  $ticketResult = $conn->query($ticketQuery);

  // Verificar si se obtuvieron resultados y obtener los datos
  if ($ticketResult && $ticketResult->num_rows > 0) {
    while ($ticketRow = $ticketResult->fetch_assoc()) {
      $ticketId = $ticketRow['id'];
      $imagen = $ticketRow['Imagen'];
      $pelicula = $ticketRow['Pelicula'];
      $nombre = $ticketRow['Nombre'];
      $nomT = $ticketRow['NomT'];
      $pais = $ticketRow['Pais'];
      $cine = $ticketRow['Cine'];
      $texto = $ticketRow['Texto'];
      $personas = $ticketRow['Personas'];
      $horarios = $ticketRow['Horario'];
      ?>
      <div class="ticket">
        <img src="<?php echo $imagen; ?>" alt="Imagen del producto" class="ticket-image">
        <div class="ticket-info">
          <p><strong>Pelicula:</strong>
            <?php echo $pelicula; ?>
          </p>
          <p><strong>Nombre:</strong>
            <?php echo $nombre; ?>
          </p>
          <p><strong>Número de Tarjeta:</strong>
            <?php echo $nomT; ?>
          </p>
          <p><strong>País:</strong>
            <?php echo $pais; ?>
          </p>
          <p><strong>Cine:</strong>
            <?php echo $cine; ?>
          </p>
          <p><strong>Cantidad de Personas:</strong>
            <?php echo $texto; ?>
            <?php echo $personas; ?>
          </p>
          <p><strong>Horario:</strong>
            <?php echo $horarios; ?>
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="ticket-actions">
          <form method="POST" action="../lista/index1.php">
            <input type="hidden" name="ticket_id" value="<?php echo $ticketId; ?>">
            <?php
            $_SESSION['opr'] = "modificar";
            ?>
            <button type="submit" class="btn-editar">Editar</button>
          </form>
          <form method="POST" action="">
            <input type="hidden" name="ticket_id" value="<?php echo $ticketId; ?>">
            <button type="submit" class="btn-eliminar">Eliminar</button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
      <?php
    }
  } else {
    // Manejar el caso cuando no se encuentren resultados
    echo 'No se encontraron resultados.';
  }

  // Cerrar la conexión a la base de datos
  $conn->close();
  ?>
```

Como se puede observar en esta parte mando mi variable que contiene mi el id guardado para asi poder recuperarlo y asi mismo poder ocuparlo.

```
<form method="POST" action="../lista/index1.php">
        <input type="hidden" name="ticket_id" value="<?php echo $ticketId; ?>">
        <?php
        $_SESSION['opr'] = "modificar";
        ?>
        <button type="submit" class="btn-editar">Editar</button>
      </form>
```

El problema viene aqui, porque quiero editar los datos de mi tabla y para hacerlo necesito pasar por 4 paginas diferentes entonces en el siguiente archivo es donde me doy cuenta y prosigo a guardar el Id en un objeto XMLHttpRequest, para asi poder ocuparlo en los archivos php.
Pero cuando lo hago en la consola me carga el Id guardado correctamente
*Inserto el bloque de javascript y captura de lo que me sale en pantalla con los console.logs, aclarando que el "19" es el valor de mi id*

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
// Obtén una referencia al botón de guardar imagen
var botonGuardar = document.getElementById('guardarImagen');
// Agrega un evento click al botón
botonGuardar.addEventListener('click', function () {
    // obtener el item del localstorage
    var ticketID = localStorage.getItem('ticket_id');
    console.log(ticketID);
    // Crear un objeto XMLHttpRequest
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    // Define la función de callback cuando la solicitud se completa exitosamente
    xhr.onload = function () {
        if (xhr.status >= 200 && xhr.status < 400) {
            // La solicitud se realizó correctamente
            console.log('El archivo .php se mandó correctamente.');
            console.log('Datos enviados:', ticketID); // Imprimir el dato enviado en la consola
            console.log(xhr.responseText); // impresion de la respuesta del archivo .php
            //window.location.href = 'index1_5.php'; // Redirigir a index1_5.php
        } else {
            // Hubo un error en la solicitud
            console.error('Se produjo un error al enviar el archivo .php.');
        }
    };

    // Define la URL del archivo PHP que recibirá los datos
    var url = 'index1_5.php';

    // Crea un objeto FormData y agrega el ticket_id como un campo
    var formData = new FormData();
    if (ticketID) {
        formData.append('ticket_id', ticketID);
        console.log('Se agregó con éxito el campo ticket_id al FormData.');
    }

    // Abre la conexión y envía la solicitud POST
    xhr.open('POST', url, true);
    xhr.send(formData);
});
```

});

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Con el **xhr.responseText** tambien cargo como actua el archivo .php con los datos enviados, (Aclarando que el session lo ocupe para guardar la variable "opr" con el valor de "modificar" para saber que es lo que se va hacer en cada caso ya que tambien esta la session con el valor de "nuevo" para añadir un nuevo registro), *Inserto pedazo del codigo del archivo donde quiero recuperar de nuevo mi Id y lo que me sale en la consola*

```
<?php
session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION['opr'])) {
    $_SESSION['opr'] = "nuevo";
}

echo ($_SESSION['opr']);

var_dump($_POST);

if ($_SESSION['opr'] === 'modificar') {
    //Conectar a la base de datos
    $conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'cine');
    // Verificar si la conexión es exitosa
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Error en la conexión a la base de datos: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }

    $ticketId=$_POST['ticket_id'];
    echo($ticketId);
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En resumen el Id se guardo en la pagina que llamaremos "guardar.php", el cual contiene un botón que se encarga de hacer lo anterior de guardar el Id y subirlo por un objeto **XMLHttpRequest** para ocuparlo en los siguientes archivos, y que tambien es el que al mismo tiempo se encarga de redirigir a la siguiente pagina que le vamos a llamar "seguir.php", el error esta que cuando intento llegar a al archivo "seguir.php", ya que es como si mi archivo el que se encarga de guardar el Id no funcionara porque me aparece que la linea **$ticketId=$_POST['ticket_id'];** esta vacia.

**Inserto imagen del error que me sale al redirigir a la siguiente pagina**
[image]

La parte del error del SQL es porque no se puede recuperar el Id asi que ese error no importa, ya que solucionando la parte donde quiero recuperar mi Id se solucionara o eso espero

Inserto parte del codigo php donde recojo de nuevo mi Id para guardarlo en un input que despues el boton se encargara de guardarlo en el localstorage.

```
<?php
 session_start();

 if (!isset($_SESSION['opr'])) {

  $_SESSION['opr'] = "nuevo";

 }

if ($_SESSION['opr'] === 'modificar') {


//Conectar a la base de datos

$conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'cine')
```

;
// Verificar si la conexión es exitosa

```
if ($conn->connect_error) {

  die("Error en la conexión a la base de datos: " . $conn->connect_error);

}

$ticketId = $_POST['ticket_id'];

// Obtener los datos del ticket específico desde la base de datos

$ticketQuery = "SELECT Nombre, NomT FROM tickets WHERE id = $ticketId";

$ticketResult = $conn->query($ticketQuery);

// Verificar si se obtuvieron resultados y obtener los datos
if ($ticketResult && $ticketResult->num_rows > 0) {
  // Obtener los valores del ticket
  $ticketRow = $ticketResult->fetch_assoc();
  $nombre = $ticketRow['Nombre'];
  $nomT = $ticketRow['NomT'];
} else {
  // Manejar el caso cuando no se encuentren resultados
  $nombre = "";
  $nomT = "";
}
echo (
  "
<button>SIGUIENTE</button>
<h1>Introduce tus datos</h1>

<form action='' class='container'>
  <div class='input-container'>
    <div class='input-content'>
      <div class='input-dist'>
        <div class='input-type'>
          <input type='hidden' name='dato' id='dato' value='$ticketId'>
          <input id='nombre' placeholder='Nombre' required='' type='text' class='input-is' value='$nombre'>
          <input id='numeroTarjeta' placeholder='Numero de tarjeta' required='' type='password' class='input-is' value='$nomT'>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
<script src='js/datos.js'></script>"
);
```

Tambien inserto la pagina que llamamos donde activo la funcion del javaScript el cual se encarga de guardarlo en el objeto **XMLHttpRequest** y asi poder ocuparlo en los demas archivos (Solo lo pongo por las dudas...).

```
<?php

 session_start();
```

if (!isset($_SESSION['opr'])) {

```
  $_SESSION['opr'] = "nuevo";
```

}

if ($_SESSION['opr'] === 'modificar') {
echo (
"
SIGUIENTE

```
     <section class='movies container'>
        <section>
           <div class='swiper mySwiper'>
              <div class='swiper-wrapper'>
                 <div class='swiper-slide'>
                    <img src='images/1.jpg' alt=' data-texto='The Martian'>
                 </div>
                 <div class='swiper-slide'>
                    <img src='images/2.jpg' alt=' data-texto='Interstellar'>
                 </div>
                 <div class='swiper-slide'>
                    <img src='images/3.jpg' alt=' data-texto='Catch me if you can'>
                 </div>
                 <div class='swiper-slide'>
                    <img src='images/4.jpg' alt=' data-texto='Meet Joe Black'>
                 </div>
                 <div class='swiper-slide'>
                    <img src='images/5.jpg' alt=' data-texto='The Notebook'>
                 </div>
                 <div class='swiper-slide'>
                    <img src='images/6.jpg' alt=' data-texto='Scream'>
                 </div>
                 <div class='swiper-slide'>
                    <img src='images/7.jpg' alt=' data-texto='Clueless'>
                 </div>
                 <div class='swiper-slide'>
                    <img src='images/8.jpg' alt=' data-texto='Si tuviera 30'>
                 </div>
                 <div class='swiper-slide'>
                    <img src='images/9.jpg' alt=' data-texto='Hereditary'>
                 </div>
                 <div class='swiper-slide'>
                    <img src='images/10.jpg' alt=' data-texto='Steve Universe'>
                 </div>
                 <div class='swiper-slide'>
                    <img src='images/11.jpg' alt=' data-texto='Little Women'>
                 </div>
                 <div class='swiper-slide'>
                    <img src='images/12.jpg' alt=' data-texto='10 Things I hate About You'>
                 </div>
                 <div class='swiper-slide'>
                    <img src='images/13.jpg' alt=' data-texto='Last Night in Soho'>
                 </div>
                 <div class='swiper-slide'>
                    <img src='images/14.jpg' alt=' data-texto='Don't Worry Darling'>
                 </div>
                 <div class='swiper-slide'>
                    <img src='images/15.jpg' alt=' data-texto='All of those voices'>
                 </div>
              </div>
           </div>
        </section>
  
     </section>
  
     <script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@9/swiper-bundle.min.js'></script>
     <script src='script.js'></script>
     <script src='js/Id.js'></script>
     <script src='js/carrusel.js'></script>"
  );
```

}

Perdon por llenar todo pero en verdad estoy perdisimo del porque no funciona, ya borre como 20 veces el cache del navegador pensando que era eso pero no funciono.

y tambien por tener algunas faltas de ortografia o por no expresarme de la mejor manera, de ante mano gracias!

Si ocupan algo más del codigo con gusto se los puedo llegar a dar.

Comment: No está demás advertir que tu consulta es vulnerable a inyecciones SQL. Referencia: [¿Cómo evitar la inyección SQL en PHP?](/q/18232)

Answer (score 0):

> En resumen el Id se guardo en la pagina que llamaremos "guardar.php",
> el cual contiene un botón que se encarga de hacer lo anterior de
> guardar el Id y subirlo por un objeto XMLHttpRequest para ocuparlo en
> los siguientes archivos, y que tambien es el que al mismo tiempo se
> encarga de redirigir a la siguiente pagina que le vamos a llamar
> "seguir.php", el error esta que cuando intento llegar a al archivo
> "seguir.php", ya que es como si mi archivo el que se encarga de
> guardar el Id no funcionara porque me aparece que la linea
> $ticketId=$_POST['ticket_id']; esta vacia.
>
> Inserto imagen del error que me sale al redirigir a la siguiente
> pagina

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Recalquemos lo siguiente en especifico:

> **Al mismo tiempo se encarga de redirigir a la siguiente pagina que
> le vamos a llamar "seguir.php", el error esta que cuando intento
> llegar a al archivo "seguir.php", ya que es como si mi archivo el que
> se encarga de guardar el Id no funcionara porque me aparece que la
> linea `$ticketId=$_POST['ticket_id'];` esta vacía.**

Lo que termina ocurriendo es claro, lo que pasa es que si estas haciendo luego una re dirección a un archivo 'X' recuerda que `POST` es un tipo de petición `WEB` y solo sostiene información que llega y se pega en su archivo al momento de que crear la solicitud, los datos de `POST` existen y existirán unicamente al momento de realizar la petición en el archivo que fue solicitado, pero **NO** sostendrá ni pasara esta información a otros documentos, al momento de redirigir, `POST` es limpiado, y no solo eso, si intentáramos forzar otra petición `POST` para pasar por el mismo método, se consideraran peticiones distintas con información distinta y única, por ende, es como si nunca hubieses mandado información (A menos que explícitamente lo hagas, que es básicamente volver a realizar otra petición `POST` a tu ultimo archivo pasándole de nuevo la misma información).

Yo sugiero entonces dos opciones, o una de dos, o mandas la información por `GET` al momento de hacer la redireccion y la recuperas por el mismo metodo (la forma mas insegura):

```
header('Location: rutaAlArchivo.php?ticket_id=$ticketId');
```

O en caso de que la redireccion no la hagas desde `PHP` sino en javascript:

```
location.href = `rutaAlArchivo.php?ticket_id=${ticketID}`;
```

Y la recuperas en tu otro archivo por `GET` en vez de por `POST`:

```
$ticketId = $_GET['ticket_id'];
```

O la otra forma que es guardar tu valor en `$_SESSION` y recuperarla desde el `$_SESSION` en tu otro archivo:

```
session_start();

$_SESSION['ticket_id'] = $ticketId;

//Redireccion
```

Y en tu otro archivo:

```
session_start();

$ticketId = $_SESSION['ticket_id'];
```

De todas maneras tener en cuenta que acabo de ver que estas intentando usar `XMLHttpRequest()` para la petición, lo cual genera un inconveniente, pues lo que he expuesto funcionaria si las redirecciones las hace un formulario en cada pagina, lo cual parece no ser el caso, sin embargo si realmente haces redirecciones entonces sigue habiendo algo que no cuadra, pues normalmente nosotros al momento de enviar información a un archivo mediante `AJAX` normalmente procesamos la data en ese mismo archivo y la devolvemos al cliente directamente, no intentamos `redirigir` a otro archivo, las redirecciones crean conflictos con `AJAX`, otra cosa que puedes hacer para poder arreglar el problema es que modifiques el código e importes aquella lógica necesaria del otro archivo en tu archivo principal de la petición:

```
 require_once 'logicaArchivoSiguiente.php';
```

Sin embargo esto último es muy sucio y yo consideraría que es lo menos recomendable que podrías hacer pues tiende a crear más conflictos de los que soluciona a menos de que tú lógica esté en un contenedor o no impacte en las funciones / método de tu archivo principal.

Si bien es buena la idea de separar la lógica en varios archivos y de hecho (esta bien que lo hagas), en el caso de las peticiones WEB y específicamente `POST` recordemos que los datos **NO serán** transportados de un archivo a otro haciendo unicamente una redireccion normal, es por esto que es importante que el archivo al que hagas la petición `POST` sea el mismo que devuelva la información final.

> Por ultimo y lo que mas recomendaría yo hacer

para que no tengas que hacer tantos cambios y que puedas hacer uso de tus archivos tal cual como lo vienes haciendo de forma totalmente separada y que no tengas que importar archivos en otros, es que en vez de realizar una redireccion normal al otro archivo como lo intentas hacer en el código:

```
if (xhr.status >= 200 && xhr.status < 400) {
  // La solicitud se realizó correctamente
  console.log('El archivo .php se mandó correctamente.');
  console.log('Datos enviados:', ticketID); // Imprimir el dato enviado en la consola
  console.log(xhr.responseText); // impresion de la respuesta del archivo .php
  //window.location.href = 'index1_5.php'; // Redirigir a index1_5.php
} else {
  // Hubo un error en la solicitud
  console.error('Se produjo un error al enviar el archivo .php.');
}
```

Crees una nueva petición `XmlHttpRequest` con método `POST` al obtener tu información hacia el otro archivo, deberás pasarle para ello obviamente tu nueva información cuando ya tengas tu informacion que viene desde tu otra peticion `XmlHttpRequest`:

```
if (xhr.status >= 200 && xhr.status < 400) {
  // La solicitud se realizó correctamente
  console.log('El archivo .php se mandó correctamente.');
  console.log('Datos enviados:', ticketID); // Imprimir el dato enviado en la consola
  console.log(xhr.responseText); // impresion de la respuesta del archivo .php
  
  //EN VEZ DE REDIRIGIR CREAMOS UNA NUEVA XmlHttpRequest
  //window.location.href = 'index1_5.php'; // Redirigir a index1_5.php
  
  
  //Simulemos que ya tienes toda la peticion xhr creada 
  xhr2.send();
} else {
  // Hubo un error en la solicitud
  console.error('Se produjo un error al enviar el archivo .php.');
}
```

Sin embargo para que no tengas que estar repitiendo tanto la creación de una `XmlHttpRequest` de manera completa y desde cero sugeriría crear tu propia función que se encargue de realizar una petición ajax y devuelva una respuesta, de esta manera sera re utilizable y limpiaremos y acortaremos bastante nuestro código:

```
async function ajax(url, metodo, data)
{
   //Tu logica de petición
}

if (xhr.status >= 200 && xhr.status < 400) {
  // La solicitud se realizó correctamente
  console.log('El archivo .php se mandó correctamente.');
  console.log('Datos enviados:', ticketID); // Imprimir el dato enviado en la consola
  console.log(xhr.responseText); // impresion de la respuesta del archivo .php

  //EN VEZ DE REDIRIGIR CREAMOS UNA NUEVA XmlHttpRequest
  //window.location.href = 'index1_5.php'; // Redirigir a index1_5.php

  const resp = await ajax(url, metodo, data);
} else {
  // Hubo un error en la solicitud
  console.error('Se produjo un error al enviar el archivo .php.');
}
```

Sin embargo esto ultimo de crear nuestra propia función que cree peticiones `XmlHttpRequest` se nos sale un poco mas de las manos para esta pregunta y realmente es un tema que seria para otra pregunta aparte, te sugiero esa opción por si la deseas implementar.

Por supuesto el código que posees dificulta un poco el dar a entender lo que quiero mencionar, así que dare un ejemplo minificado de que es lo que deberías hacer o lograr si decides usar esta ultima alternativa.

Nota: El siguiente código requiere el uso de la librería `jQuery` para poder funcionar, es solo un ejemplo que permite entender de mejor forma como deberías implementar lo ultimo que mencione:

```
const data = {
  ticket_id: 'ejemplo_ticket'
}

$.ajax({
  url: 'archivoPrincipal.php',
  method: 'POST',
  data
})
.then(res => {
  
  data2 = {id_ticket: res, ...otra_informacion}
  
  //Hacemos uso de la informacion de la peticion y enviamos al archivo siguiente.php
  $.ajax({
    url: 'siguiente.php',
    method: 'POST',
    data2
  }).then(d => {
    console.log('exito!');
  })
  .catch(e => {
    console.log(e);
  });
  
})
.catch(e => {
  console.log(e.message);
})
```

Esto es entonces basicamente un ejemplo mas sencillo de entender de lo que deberias conseguir en tu codigo pero usando una `XmlHttpRequest` el cual es un buen ejercicio para conocer e implementar ajax sin el uso de librerías.

Si bien el código anteriormente descrito se puede mejorar para ser mas legible aun y evitar cosas como el `Callback hell` o  el `Promise hell`, he decidido mantener todos estos conceptos aparte y darte la versión mas sencilla y entendible para no confundirte, pero basicamente la logica es que una vez realices la primera peticion, en vez de redirigir crees otra peticion hacia tu archivo siguiente con los datos que necesites.

Esto es lo que puedo decir hasta el momento de los problemas que surgen en tu código y diferentes alternativas de como podrías solucionarlos, espero puedan ayudarte a solucionarlo.